# MPAndroidChart (PieChart) not showing highlighted Slice for Rounded corners

Tags: java, android, kotlin, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I am trying to create a chart like below, For my android application using MPAndroidChart(PieChart). I was unable to figure out, how to make the Piechart's edges as round edged. then I saw  `pieChart.setDrawRoundedSlices(true)` this line of code helped me in achieving below design. now after adding this line PieChart is not showing highlighted Slice.

**GIT Hub Issue Ticket :** https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/4804

**Desired Design** with highlighted slice.

[image: Design Required]

**Currently Developed** unable to get highlighted Slice.

[image: PieChart Example]

**Dummy Project** with highlighted Slice without curved edges.

[image: Dummy Project]

Comment: Any chance you can share how you got to the second screenshot?

Comment: @confusedstudent btw this was a bug now don't know if it's fixed or not.